# Equivalent of File.ReadLines(filepath) C# in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, linq, csv, electron

In my current `C#` code, I used the `.NET` package `File.ReadLines()`. Are there any ways to re-write that code in Javascript?

```
var csvArray = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

I know that `LINQ Select` could be used in Javascript. My **current progress** is on reading a `CSV` file. Kindly check my JS code below.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var csv = require('fast-csv');
    var filepath = $('#appFilePathInput').value();

    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function(data){
        //Should I put the LINQ Select and Split toArray code here?
    });
    .on('data', function(data){
        console.log('Read Finished');
    });
```

**GOAL** is to `read the local CSV file to an Array` in `JavaScript`.

Kindly help me `improve my existing code` since it is my first time writing code in pure Javascript.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the new line `\n` with a comma, then do a split by comma

```
var data = "Server1, Server2, Server3 \n 1.5, 2.9, 3.1"
var result = data.replace("\n", ",").split(",");
```

you can check the result in the console in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9oa25k2t/

Comment: I opened my CSV file on notepad and did not find any `\n`. Is that normal? And where should I put that code?

Comment: \n just means line break(new line, enter key), it could also be represented by \r\n, see what works for you split("\n") or split("\r\n")

Comment: Wow. Thanks for enlightening me regardin `\n`. However, could you give an example on what would the **value** of `result` be? Let's say my CSV file's first lines are: `Server1, Server2, Server3 \n 1.5, 2.9, 3.1`. Could you help me trace it using the code that your proposed as an answer?

Comment: you actually need to replace the new line with a comma then do a split by comma, i updated my answer